# how to get date from CDBVariant?

Tags: sql-server, database, mfc, visual-studio-2015, odbc

i am trying to get the the day ,month ,year from sql server using CDBVariant but i cant able to do that my code is below

what i want is just cout the day ,month ,year in my own format
like this

> 3 jan 1990

in my student table i use date type not the date/time so i want to just cout the date in my own format because the date i get from database is **year-month-date** i want to show it as **date-month-year**

I cant able to convert CDBVariant::m_pdate to ctime

```
    CDBVariant date; 
    rs.GetFieldValue(short(2),date);//

    CTime a(date.m_pdate->year, date.m_pdate->month, date.m_pdate->day);

    cout << " date is:" << a.GetYear() << endl;
    a=NULL; //so the next value can be insert into ctime                
    rs.MoveNext(); // move to next tuple in table
}
```

i am making CTime a NULL so the next value can be insert becuase ctime show first time ok but after that it start adding on it dont know why all i want is just get the date from database and cout it.

Comment: What **is** the problem? Also consider editing your question, removing code that is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Avoid using `system("pause")`. Use `cin.get();` instead.

Comment: `a=NULL;` doesn't do what you think it does. You need to learn about object lifetimes and that objects aren't pointers. Consider picking up one or more books from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329).

Comment: the data i am getting from database is 2015-12-15 in CDBVariant date   so how i can convert that into CTime variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to convert `CDBVariant` to `COleDateTime` is the following:

```
CDBVariant var;

if(var.m_dwType == DBVT_DATE) 
{
    COleDateTime timestamp(var.m_pdate->year,var.m_pdate->month,var.m_pdate->day,
                     var.m_pdate->hour,var.m_pdate->minute,var.m_pdate->second);
    CString str = timestamp.Format(_T("%B %d, %Y"));
}
```

Comment: It does actually work. You should use `CString str = timestamp.Format(_T("%B %d, %Y"));` to get the printable string.

Comment: the problem was that the data i was getting from database was not pointing to the date part so i use ``rs.GetFieldValue(L"date",date, SQL_C_TIMESTAMP);``

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've found the data type reported by `CDBVariant::m_dwType` to be a bit dodgy when used in conjunction with SQL data.

You're best bet is probably to check what kind of (SQL) data is being returned in the [CDBVariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdbvariant-class?view=vs-2019) first, using the `CRecordset::GetODBCFieldInfo` function, and then "tell" `CRecordset::GetFieldValue()` the default C data type:

```
CRecordSet oSet;        // Hold the set of records returned by SQL query
CDBVariant oVar;        // get the variant values from the each of the fields in SQL resultSet
CODBCFieldInfo oFinfo;  // to get the fieldinfo reported by ODBC
TIMESTAMP_STRUCT myDtm; // DateTime structure for accessing the components of dateTimes from SQL

...     // some other code to populate the oSet

cnsNumOsetCols = oSet.GetODBCFieldCount();

// Iterate thru the columns in the oSet
for (idxCol = 0; idxCol < cnsNumOsetCols; idxCol++)
{
    // Use the ODBC info from the resultSet
    oSet.GetODBCFieldInfo((short)idxCol, oFinfo);
    if ((oFinfo.m_nSQLType == SQL_DATE))
    {
        // Specify the C data type when retreiving the data from the variant
        oSet.GetFieldValue((short)idxCol, oVar, SQL_C_DATE);
        myDtm = oVar.m_pdate;

        ... // some other code to manipulate the date
    }
}
```

However, if you're not using a CRecordSet, and only using the CDBVariant for its ability to handle any kind of data at runtime, then the above probably isn't goint to be of any help.